# ZipFile does not list all entries in a jar

Tags: java, jar

ZipFile (and, by extension, JarFile) silently ignores files with filename encoding other than UTF-8, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

ZipFile has other issues as well, starting with misleading exceptions, and continuing on.
Avoid like a plague.
Use ZipFile from commons-compress.